# ¿Porque mis bases de datos estan dentro de este simbolo? - PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

en el día de hoy vengo con una duda tonta pero que me tiene intranquilo. Siempre he usado workbench para mi gestion de bases de datos pero ahora resulta que necesito de phpmyadmin para hacer un clon de mi base de datos.

El problema es que cuando lo abri me encontre con que dos de mis bases de datos estaban dentro de un icono medio extraño como libros en una caja.

[image: Foto de icono raro]

Y dicho icono esta nombrado como BD, quiero relajarme y pensar que nada mas está agrupando todas las tablas que llamadas bd_**** pero no lo sé y me tiene preocupado.

Que significa ese simbolo?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

el simbolo significa agrupar
esto suede cuando 1 o mas base de datos contienen un mismo prefijo en tu caso:

## **bd_**

ejemplo:

[image: agrupar database]